# How can I OR union cases?

Tags: f#

I referenced this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547125.aspx). However, I still don't see how I can OR the following union cases:

```
match count with
| x when x < 2 -> grid |> setCell { X=x; Y=y; State=Dead }
| x when x > 3 -> grid |> setCell { X=x; Y=y; State=Dead }
| _            -> grid
```

I want to do this:

```
match count with
| x when x < 2
| x when x > 3 -> grid |> setCell { X=x; Y=y; State=Dead }
| _            -> grid
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a boolean OR operator ||

```
match count with
| x when x > 3 || x < 2 -> grid |> setCell { X=x; Y=y; State=Dead }
| _                     -> grid
```

Answer (score 3):

How about inverting the matches?

```
match count with
| 1
| 2 -> grid
| _ -> grid |> setCell { X=count; Y=y; State=Dead }
```

Comment: Thx Mark. The challenge that I have with your suggestion is that I am unable to OR all values greater than 3 and less than 3.

Comment: @ScottNimrod : Why would you need to? Mark's literal cases should be `2` and `3`, but other than that it's semantically equivalent to what's in your question.